# In capacitor/android/typeorm/"@capacitor-community/sqlite", unable to query blob column

Tags: android, sqlite, electron, typeorm, capacitor-plugin

I'm trying to read a sqlite db table with **blob** column using `typeorm` and `@capacitor-community/sqlite` plugin in Android phone in a capacitor project.
This returns `[B@c47681d` instead of `data:image/png;base64,UklGRqhp...`

I'm reusing typeorm code (entities, querying logic, etc.) from an `electron` project. These same code works in `electron` platform. Only difference is that it run in node with `@journeyapps/sqlcipher` driver.

I also experimented with using just `@capacitor-community/sqlite` plugin in `capacitor & android` **without** `typeorm`. This also works fine.

However, when I try to combine `typeorm` with `@capacitor-community/sqlite`, I'm getting the above issue.

There are a lot of `typeorm` entities already implemented and working in `electron` project that I would like to reuse in `capacitor & android` project with `@capacitor-community/sqlite` plugin. If not, I have to port all those functionality.

Any help in this is highly appreciated. Other column types like `number`, `string` are working fine. Only issue is with `blob` type.

### **Working**:
`electron/node/"@journeyapps/sqlcipher"`

```
@Entity()
export class Teach {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    _id: string;

    @Column({
        type: "blob",
        nullable: true,
        transformer: {
            to: (value) => value?.buffer,
            from: (value) => value.toString("base64")
        },
    })
    img: string;
}
```

---

```
const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "sqlite",
    database: dbFile,
    driver: require("@journeyapps/sqlcipher"),
    key: "dummykey",
    flags: 0x00000001, // SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY
    entities: [Teach],
    logging: true,
});

this.dataSource = await AppDataSource.initialize();
this.repo = this.dataSource.getRepository(Teach);
```

---

```
const rows = await this.repo.find({ where: null });
```

---

**Working**:
`capacitor/android/"@capacitor-community/sqlite"`

---

```
let db = null;
window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
    name: dbName,
    location: "default",
    key: "dummykey",
},
(result: SQLitePlugin) => {db = result},
(err) => {...});
```

---

```
const query = "SELECT _id, BASE64(img) AS img FROM teach;";
// **BTW**: with query="SELECT _id, img FROM teach;", I was getting "[B@c47681d"
const params = [];

db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(query, params, (tx, rs) => {...success...}, (tx, err) => {...});
},
(err) => {...});
```

---

**NOT Working**:
`capacitor/android/typeorm/"@capacitor-community/sqlite"`

---

```
@Entity()
export class Teach {
    // same as above
}
```

---

```
const sqliteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite);

const { result: isSecretStored } = await sqliteConnection.isSecretStored();
if (!isSecretStored) {
    await sqliteConnection.setEncryptionSecret("dummykey");
}

const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "capacitor",
    database: dbName,
    driver: sqliteConnection,
    key: "dummykey",
    encrypted: true,
    mode: "secret",
    flags: 0x00000001, // SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY
    entities: [Teach],
    logging: true,
});

this.dataSource = await AppDataSource.initialize();
this.repo = this.dataSource.getRepository(Teach);
```

---

```
const rows = await this.repo.find({ where: null });
// for img, I'm getting `[B@c47681d` instead of `data:image/png;base64,UklGRqhp...`
```

---

**EDIT**
I also tried raw query (with the same query as above) as follows:

```
// const rows = await this.repo.find({ where: null });
const rows = await table.repo.query(
    "SELECT _id, BASE64(img) AS img FROM teach;"
);
```

but I'm getting the following error in `android logcat`:

```
com.getcapacitor.community.database.sqlite.RetHandler: *** ERROR Query: in selectSQL cursor no such function: BASE64: , while compiling: SELECT _id, BASE64(img) AS img FROM teach;
```